# gstreamer: multiple RTSP clients connecting at the same time makes the video stream crash

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, rtsp

**Quick summary**

video stream crashes if multiple clients connect at the same time due to the clients (all but 1) that skip the media-configure callback trying to change the bitrate by accessing a not yet configured pipeline. I'm asking how to wait with calling `change_bitrate` as long as the `configure-media` callback hasn't yet finished.

**Detailed overview**

I'm developing a door phone application that shows video footage of a user (that just rang the door) over the RTSP protocol on one or multiple screens (called **clients** from now on) in e.g. an appartment building.

When the application is running, it will not create a pipeline before the first client has connected. A new client callback is created in the following way:

```
    /* Configure Callbacks */
    /* Create new client handler (Called on new client connect) */
    LOG_debug("Creating 'client-connected' signal handler");
    g_signal_connect(info.server, "client-connected", G_CALLBACK(new_client_handler), &info);
```

Which calls this function as soon as a client has connected:

```
/**
 * new_client_handler
 * Called by rtsp server on a new client connection
 */
static void new_client_handler(GstRTSPServer *server, GstRTSPClient *client, struct stream_info *si)
{
    DEBUG_ENTER;

    /* Used to initiate the media-configure callback */
    static gboolean first_run = TRUE;

    GstRTSPConnection *connection = gst_rtsp_client_get_connection(client);
    if (connection == NULL)
    {
        LOG_err("Could not get RTSP connection");
        DEBUG_EXIT;
        return;
    }

    GstRTSPUrl *url = gst_rtsp_connection_get_url(connection);
    if (url == NULL)
    {
        LOG_err("Could not get RTSP connection URL");
        DEBUG_EXIT;
        return;
    }


    si->num_cli++;

    gchar* uri = gst_rtsp_url_get_request_uri(url);
    LOG_info("[%d]A new client %s has connected", si->num_cli, uri);
    g_free(uri);

    si->connected = TRUE;

    /* Create media-configure handler */
    /*relevant part for question*/
    if (si->num_cli == 1)
    { /* Initial Setup */

        /**
         * Stream info is required, which is only
         * available on the first connection. Stream info is created
         * upon the first connection and is never destroyed after that.
         */
        if (first_run == TRUE)
        {
            LOG_debug("Creating 'media-configure' signal handler");
            g_signal_connect(si->factory, "media-configure", G_CALLBACK(media_configure_handler),
                    si);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        change_bitrate(si); //This makes video stream crash if 'media_configure_handler' isn't yet finished
    }

    /* Create new client_close_handler */
    LOG_debug("Creating 'closed' signal handler");
    g_signal_connect(client, "closed", G_CALLBACK(client_close_handler), si);

    first_run = FALSE;
    DEBUG_EXIT;
}
```

When a client is the first one to connect, it sets up the `media-configure` callback to initialize the pipeline. The configuration code looks like this:

```
**
 * media_configure_handler
 * Setup pipeline when the stream is first configured
 */
static void media_configure_handler(GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory, GstRTSPMedia *media,
        struct stream_info *si)
{
    DEBUG_ENTER;

    si->media = media;

    LOG_info("[%d]Configuring pipeline...", si->num_cli);

    si->pipeline = GST_BIN(gst_rtsp_media_get_element(media)); //Pipeline gets configured here
    setup_elements(si);

    if (si->num_cli == 1)
    {
        /* Create Msg Event Handler */
        LOG_debug("Creating 'periodic message' handler");
        g_timeout_add(si->msg_rate * 1000, (GSourceFunc) periodic_msg_handler, si);
    }
    DEBUG_EXIT;
}
```

A second (or nth) client that connects skips the media configuration step and instead goes to `change_bitrate`. Here the bitrate is adjusted based on the amount of connected clients.

```
/**
 * change_bitrate
 * handle changing of bitrates
 */
static void change_bitrate(struct stream_info *si)
{
    DEBUG_ENTER;

    int c = si->curr_bitrate;
    int step = (si->max_bitrate - si->min_bitrate) / si->steps;
    GstElement *elem = search_pipeline(si->pipeline, "enc"); //crashes due to an unitialized pipeline
    const gchar *name = g_ascii_strdown(G_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(elem), -1);
    GstStructure *extra_controls;
...
}
```

This all works fine if a single client connects first. Later, the connection can handle multiple clients and adjusts the bitrate accordingly.

**The problem arises if the first connection is by multiple clients**:
In this case, both clients enter an instance of `new_client_handler`, in which the **first one** will set up the `media_configure_handler`. The **second connection** tries to **change the bitrate**, but **fails**  because the **pipeline is not yet configured** by the callback.

How can i make the second (and nth) connection wait until the media configure callback has finished and thus a pipeline is available?

Comment: Would wrapping the entire bottom part of `new_client_handler` in a mutex and/or semaphore work? (e.g.) `pthread_mutex_lock(...); if (si->num_cli == 1) { ... } else  { change_bitrate() } pthread_mutex_unlock();` Or, some other appropriate locking mechanism

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would not work. You would only lock the creation of the callback method, not the callback itself. `pthread_mutex_unlock` would be called before the callback even triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this in the end with the following code (in function `new_client_handler`)

```
    /* Create media-configure handler */
    if (si->num_cli == 1)
    { /* Initial Setup */

        /**
         * Stream info is required, which is only
         * available on the first connection. Stream info is created
         * upon the first connection and is never destroyed after that.
         */
        if (first_run == TRUE)
        {
            LOG_debug("Creating 'media-constructor' signal handler");
            g_signal_connect(si->factory, "media-constructed", G_CALLBACK(media_configure_handler),
                    si);
        }
    }
    else if(si->pipeline != 0)
    {
        change_bitrate(si);
    }
    else
    {
        g_signal_connect(si->factory, "media-configure", G_CALLBACK(media_constructed_handler),
                si);
    }
```

Pipeline object's construction is now hooked to the `media-constructed` event, which runs before the `media-configure` event.
A second client will only change bitrate if pipeline is initialized. If not, the client hooks in the `media-configure` callback and changes bitrate there. This callback is guaranteed to run after the `media-constructed` callback.